# Inefficient gradient computation in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, automatic-differentiation

The following program runs out of memory because of the gradient computation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

@tf.function
def test(x, h):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = x
    steps = 100000
    for i in tf.range(100000):
      y = y / (y+1)
      if i == steps - 1:
        y = y - h
  grad = tape.gradient(y, h)
  return grad

x = tf.Variable(np.ones([10000]), trainable=False)
h = tf.Variable(np.ones([10000]), trainable=True)
test(x, h)
```

Without the gradient computation (setting `trainable=False` in the definition of `h`) it runs just fine and quickly.

Now the gradient with respect to `h` is really trivial in this case (it should be -1) because `h` is only used in the last step, so I would expect the tape to be almost empty and the computation to be as efficient as without gradients. I know it would work by simply writing the `y = y - h` bit outside of the for loop, however this is only a simplified case and that would be a big limitation in a more general case.

Is there a general way to make this kind of gradient computations more efficient?

Comment: Have u tried to compare the gradient calculation the `with tf.GradientTape` with `tf.function`? Another difference is that u are not using `tape.gradient` but `tf.gradients`.